# Count while parsing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, count

I am parsing a log file and reading line by line in ruby

I will get 2 values like:

iphone mobile
mobile iphone

kindle amazon
amazon kindle

What I need is count i.e. though both the values are swapped like (a,b) and (b,a) ..but it should be counted as 1 and need result as follows

"iphone mobile" => 2 
 "kindle amazon" => 2

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear: are you just counting individual lines, or specific pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that will work.  A sorted array of the input line is used as the key for the hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

# Set the default value of the hash to be zero instead of nil
h = Hash.new 0

# Process each line of the input file
ARGF.each do |line|
    # Split the line into a sorted array of words
    values = line.chomp.split.sort

    # Skip this line if there are no words on it
    next if values.length == 0

    # Increment the count for this array of words
    h[values] += 1
end

# For each key in the hash
h.keys.each do |key|
    # Join the words in the array with a space and print the count
    puts "\"#{key.join(' ')}\" => #{h[key]}"
end
```